# embed facebook albums into website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook-graph-api

I have used graph api to fetch the albums, I got all the albums into my website but the positions of the albums changing when I refresh the page. why it should happening?

I am attaching my script here.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  var albumIdsUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/<myname>/albums?callback=?";

  $.getJSON(albumIdsUrl, function(data) {
       var len = data.data.length;
       for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
            var aid = data.data[i].id;
            getAlbumCoverPhoto(data.data[i].cover_photo, data.data[i].id, data.data[i].name, data.data[i].count);
       }
    }); 

});

function getAlbumCoverPhoto(coverPhoto, albumId, albumName, count) {
        var coverPhotoUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + coverPhoto + "?callback=?";
            $.getJSON(coverPhotoUrl, function(coverPhotoData) {
                if(typeof(coverPhotoData.picture)!="undefined"){
                        htmlData = '<li><figure><a class="imageLink" href="fb_album_photos.html?id='+ albumId + '"><img src="' + coverPhotoData.picture + '" /></a></figure><figcaption>'+albumName+'</br>'+count+' Photos</figcaption></li>';
                        $('#FBalbum').append(htmlData);
                }
            });             
    }  
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The data being returned isn't always in the same order so it needs sorted if you want consistent results.

This seems to work well(but it could be cleaned up a bit):

```
  $.getJSON(albumIdsUrl, function(data) {
   var len = data.data.length;
   data.data.sort(function(a, b)
    {
        if (a.id == b.id) return 0;
        if (a.id < b.id)
            return -1;
        else
            return 1;
    });
   for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
        var aid = data.data[i].id;
        getAlbumCoverPhoto(data.data[i].cover_photo, data.data[i].id, data.data[i].name, data.data[i].count);
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I tried above code and getting same problem

Comment: I edited the sort function in my answer and the results seem more consistent than what I had.