# Displaying facebook album covers photo _n instead of _s

Tags: jquery, facebook-graph-api, getjson

I'm using the following code to grab the facebook album cover photos

[embed facebook albums into website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12005215/embed-facebook-albums-into-website)

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var albumIdsUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/<myname>/albums?callback=?";

    $.getJSON(albumIdsUrl, function(data) {
       var len = data.data.length;
       for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
        var aid = data.data[i].id;
        getAlbumCoverPhoto(data.data[i].cover_photo, data.data[i].id, data.data[i].name, data.data[i].count);
   }
}); 

});

function getAlbumCoverPhoto(coverPhoto, albumId, albumName, count) {
    var coverPhotoUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + coverPhoto + "?callback=?";
        $.getJSON(coverPhotoUrl, function(coverPhotoData) {
            if(typeof(coverPhotoData.picture)!="undefined"){
                    htmlData = '<li><figure><a class="imageLink" href="fb_album_photos.html?id='+ albumId + '"><img src="' + coverPhotoData.picture + '" /></a></figure><figcaption>'+albumName+'</br>'+count+' Photos</figcaption></li>';
                    $('#FBalbum').append(htmlData);
            }
        });             
}  
</script>
```

This returns correctly, but gets the low res _s photo
http://photos-d.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/75750_121602837899727_4898592_s.jpg

instead of the higher res _n photo.
http://photos-d.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/75750_121602837899727_4898592_n.jpg

How do I alter this to get the correct photo?

Comment: Without seeing the JSON it would be hard to know.

Comment: How do I get that to show you?

Comment: You're using $.getJSON to get the JSON and then parsing it to display the image coverPhotoData.picture. That means the JSON is in coverPhotoData. You should be able to copy it and paste it to your question or better yet, read through it and find what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook Album object has a connection called photos. Photos connection will give the list of photos under this album.  This Photo object has a field called images. Images field will give 4 different stored representation of the photo.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/albums?fields=photos.fields(picture,images)

"data": [
    {
      "id": "10150146071831729", 
      "from": {
        "category": "Product/service", 
        "name": "Facebook", 
        "id": "20531316728"
      }, 
      "picture": "https://fbcdn-photos-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/168119_10150146071831729_5116892_s.jpg", 
      "source": "https://fbcdn-sphotos-g-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/168119_10150146071831729_5116892_n.jpg", 
      "height": 483, 
      "width": 720, 
      "images": [
        {
          "height": 1373, 
          "width": 2048, 
          "source": "https://fbcdn-sphotos-g-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/s2048x2048/168119_10150146071831729_5116892_n.jpg"
        },
```

Under images you can see the picture with the _n.jpg.